# I can't figure out what's wrong with my form code

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I was looking for some assistance on a code  for a HTML form that I am working on. What I'm trying to do with it is that I'm trying to make an alert shows up for three required fields when they are incorrectly filled out. The last name field cannot be empty, the age has to be between 18 and 35, and the gender has to have the valid terms of M, m, F, f, and any other value will return false and cannot be left blank.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function validateform(){
var age=document.myform.age.value;
var sex=document.myform.sex.value;
if (last == ""){
alert("Last name can't be blank.");
return false;}
if (age.value < 30){
return true;
}else if (age.value < 18){
alert("You are not old enough to fill out the form.")
return false;}
if (sex == 'M' || sex == 'm' || sex == 'F' || sex == 'f'){
return true;
}else if (sex == ""){
alert("Please enter a valid gender");
return false }
</script>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="aform"><table>
<form method="post">

<tr>
<td>Enter first name</td><td><input type="text"   
 name="first" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter last name</td><td><input type="text" name="last"   
 id="last" />*</td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter your age</td><td><input type="text" name="age" id="age" 
size=5 />*</td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter your sex</td><td><input type="text" name="sex" id="sex" 
size=2 />*</td></tr>
<tr><td>Enter your favorite color</td><td><input type="text"
name="color" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="verify();" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<!--` get rid of that in the script tag....

Comment: if you are less than 30 , than you are also less than 18.... Order matters...

Comment: you have verify and validateform

Comment: I recommend using an IDE or debugging in an online code tester (see https://codepen.io/pen).  Also format your code for easy reading.  It'll help you find your issues easier.

Comment: Your markup is invalid. Step one is fixing that.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Um.... <30 and <18..... not sure where I would need to add not....

Comment: Please learn how to format your code and use consistent variables.

Answer (score 0):

First off all you have used two **form tags** which is incorrect and then you have no called your function **validateform** in the form in your body tag and you have not get the parameters in the JavaScript correctly your form name is **aform** and you get the variable values by **myform** its wrong.
It should be
**var age = document.aform.age**

Answer (score 0):

There were numerous issues that were causing your code to malfunction.

You had several problems with your HTML, including a floating `<--` tag and an extra opening `form` tag that were causing the HTML to be parsed incorrectly.

2nd, you were very inconsistent with your JavaScript references and calls, such as calling an `verify` function that did not exist when you should have been calling the function `validateform`, and referencing a form called `myform` to try to grab the input when you actually used a form called `aform` in your HTML code.

There were numerous logic holes in your JavaScript evaluation as well, including the fact that it would return true without even checking all of the things to validate first, and a reference to `age.value` when this is unnecessary when you already grabbed `value` from the form when declaring the variable `age`.

Additionally, since `age` is treated as an integer in your code, it would be advisable to call `parseInt()` to convert it from a `string` to an `int`.

Here is working HTML code that fixes all of these issues:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Form</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
         <script type="text/javascript">
         function validateform(){
             var age=parseInt(document.aform.age.value);
             var sex=document.aform.sex.value;
             if (last == ""){
                alert("Last name can't be blank.");
                return false;
             }
             if (age < 18){
                alert("You are not old enough to fill out the form.")
                return false;
             }
             if (sex == 'M' || sex == 'm' || sex == 'F' || sex == 'f'){
                return true;
             }
             else{
                alert("Please enter a valid gender");
                return false; 
             }
         }
      </script>
   <body>
   <form action="" method="post" name="aform">
      <table>
   <tr>
   <td>Enter first name</td><td><input type="text"   
      name="first" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Enter last name</td><td><input type="text" name="last"   
      id="last" />*</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Enter your age</td><td><input type="text" name="age" id="age" 
      size=5 />*</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Enter your sex</td><td><input type="text" name="sex" id="sex" 
      size=2 />*</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Enter your favorite color</td><td><input type="text"
      name="color" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validateform();" /></td></tr>
   </table>
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```